# Get result for Images

Tags: image, http, get, mason

I am making the HTTP GET result for the image content from the server, initially I was getting the result as a garbled character set.

```
{�t�� �J��JQQT@@�ҥ�*((��^��{BB �� �^�F&��o���3s&�`@xf�~Cf��u����_�_^ dee��g�;/�������?r��Χ�3�@v�1p�|�=� ��.mm�{�>�?p���p�s���C]�q� B����N����}�!l`�/ �;o*�*y� ]�x��'O�S�W_�O���g=����|���D|�M-^��*�λt��U3���x�1��{Z��=��D�,\�,x�bܤ���Ç�-�����|�Z���6�5���r�~2 �#U��&�۷/�>��G�o[�(�}��Xu�@^�7�d`{��k��c��/�L�� ������s��9 �-��4ީ�g�q�6͜=��O�Bk#�)==��oݺ$p����St��Q:s6�s�rcj�|�/�4C�*�ϫ Zz��msk8|��M%_GV/YA�~GcƎ'�h��n�=:{�<ş9�A���� ~��y������޽{���� ��8w�%����k��~���6G}0�ТX��;z�' 4���}�.�U�RQ3��!���+V����DIN~DU�T�� ��y��G�2�p�g����P���y�g�r��mf=r�8}V�W{�Reh��|�}W]�[�+R��9���-[��jS� ����۵��CJ��T��������.�׎ߨ_����C�.�P��ܥ.�i#�2e�p��吝�BX|�i=͛5o� �K �~9W6l�L_~���hب1a��@�M�8�*W���y�&u�ҙ�V�Z��z�+W��J�/8km��П~�!�l�N_7h�}C��%㉏���G 4`Z�@�#�:���Xq���g����t�6R*\��E*�k�T����'s��:u�A�v�������1�裚uL� *Q�~(Ai/)�7��8w�"����s�����gu�؉�(��z�6�O��H&N�F��swF�:�a��+��0��h�������s�-]��j�f4���˯�U�!�шwT�ի��3i��zl�2�9%�P�p-Z~���D�FX�Y� ��C���v15��>�ѬY�X�xo��:�/�n)5��t6��e� �y�V:R�=6�7�6��ջ?��vIjҴ��X����Fm� ���e�SNi)��ȍƓ��[k@�-h�̸"o����?v�$�KժU髯�y�;Fw�X�����ؠ 4r��u���cNB\�[�S�PR�̝o�z�����-�Q�.o�o�p����R�QŊ�Ĝ7i�u���r�j~�Ҷ]�i��'_q+.�5��<����Qf�5j|�h��Ϝ�d7l�y�,�p ՝:wwIyL��&��h10���|���9���l0�����˩X�bT�쒥+ ���?�&��U���`l�JNݾ}�SF����&�ܥ�2W��.��{�-a:`#��ZP�Q}ɺ���sm��&G���95aTh`P�GЮ#�7��w[1�h��;���x`*�D�����@`�o7%h��u�͚!|D�#:�����xnF7���|��u\�Z�4��W��3g���`r���FhЂ0,\l�����p#0Ƈ�a֣>���:�w�Dp���g�����蘍ܗ�I;~������խ� =x��44�����]��8x���v0'�~M���&zT��3`0���b��@<�zz���(��sJ��6�\0[Pl����%�b<�%@��|�Hnh>�
```

Then I figured out that default content type of the page is "text/html", and make the content type to the "image/png" after that it's showing that, "it can't display the image because image contains error".

I am not sure is this related to the encoding issue because I am seeing the garbled characters ? after getting the image content does I need to decode/encode my result ?

Comment: Are you sure it's a png?

Comment: Yes, I am fetching the png Image from the different server

Comment: can you show us some code? how do you get the image, and how do you show it?

Comment: i'd be happy to help you if I can, but the question is not too clear, are you using html::mason? with some perl code?

Comment: try changing the content type to data

Comment: re: "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources." As you've been told several times now you won't get a "credible answer" until you show what you are actually doing. No code = no answer, simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data IS corrupt. The first 8 bytes of a valid PNG file are the decimal values `137 80 78 71 13 10 26 101`. Bytes 2 - 4 are the ASCII characters `PNG`. Your file is something else or maybe just garbage.

BTW. Your question is poorly written as it lacks the relevant code. You'll get better results from improving your question than you will from adding a bounty.